# Google Cloud Messaging Demo on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I'd like to deploy the [Google Cloud Messaging Demo Server](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html) on Google App Engine. I use Eclipse and installed the App Engine Plugin but I`m new to Web Applications and never used Google App Engine before.

Deploying the GCM Demo Server on a local Tomcat as described in the guide works perfectly.

Would be nice if someone could give me a hint.

Comment: SO is for specific coding questions, not taking people step-by-step through tutorials. You should start by describing the specific problem  you are having. Link you provided already explains how to set it up on appengine: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html#appengine-setup

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried the following:
ant -Dsdk.dir=~/Downloads/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.1 runserver -Dserver.host=ruleyourworldbe.appspot.com
Buildfile: /Users/dom/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-appengine/build.xml
BUILD FAILED
/Users/dom/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-appengine/build.xml:27: Cannot find /Users/dom/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-appengine/${sdk.dir}/config/user/ant-macros.xml imported from /Users/dom/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-appengine/build.xml

Comment: The solution I would like most is to import the demo project in eclipse and then upload it from there to the Google App Engine. But I don`t know to import the demo project in the structure that is needed for an App Engine project

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13713330/94148