# GCM server using Google app-engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I have just implemented the SDK samples for GCM client and server side. I implemented it with no problems using NetBeans(Glass Fish) as my server side and Eclipse as my client (Android). I now want to explore the use of Google App Engine as my server side. I downloaded the sample from the SDK but cant get it to compile and run....Is there any tutorial regarding this like the regular server-client GCM?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a lot at this [Using App Engine for Java](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html#appengine-setup) which is part of Google's GCM docs. Here is another blog post about a GAE based GCM server: http://www.andro.lt/2012/11/google-cloud-messaging-for-android.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Google Cloud Messaging in your Android application, you can use this free, open-source project:

[gcm4public.appspot.com](http://gcm4public.appspot.com)